# Automatically put comma and dot while typing in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a WPF app in where i have a text box, I want while the user is typing integers there they should be automatically formatted into currency by putting , and .

suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a [Masked TextBox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ba94d841-80bf-4faa-9543-2fcad04f5998).